# ¿Porque el gráfico sale al revés?

Tags: python, funciones, matplotlib

No se que paso acá, quiero imprimir el area positiva entre la curvatura de la funcion pero me sale al reves. Se rellena la curvatura negativa.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def f(x):   return x**3 - 2*x 

#Graficación 
x = np.linspace(-1.1, 1.9, 500) 
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b')
plt.axhline(color="yellow")
a = -1; b = -1.41; c = 0; d = 1.41
plt.fill_between(x, f(x), where=[(x > a) and (x < b) for x in x])
plt.fill_between(x, f(x), where=[(x > c) and (x < d) for x in x])
plt.show()

#Cálculo del Área 
x = sp.Symbol("x")
A = sp.integrate(f(x),(x, a, b)) + sp.integrate(f(x),(x, c, d))
print("Área Total =", A)
```

Answer (score 1):

La razón es porque has puesto mal las condiciones de frontera.

De la forma en la que tienes el código estás pidiendo que muestre el área entre las dos funciones, con 'x' `(x > a) and (x < b)` -> rango (-1,-1.41)... mayores que -1 y menores que -1.41 **ningún número real** cumple esta condición, por lo que no graficaría nada.

mientras que `(x > c) and (x < d)` es el rango (0,1.41) que corresponde al área negativa.

La solución es elegir bien la condición dentro de el parámetro `where`:
Una posibilidad es esta:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

def f(x):   return x**3 - 2*x 

#Graficación 
x = np.linspace(-1.1, 1.9, 500) 
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.plot(x, f(x), 'b')
plt.axhline(color="yellow")
a = -1; d = 1.8
plt.fill_between(x, f(x), where=[(x > a) and (x < d) and f(x)>0 for x in x])
plt.show()
```

La condición es en palabras: graficar para x mayores a -1 a su vez menores a 1.8 y que además f(x) es mayor a 0 (lo que corresponde al área positiva)

Comment: Pero así solo no se rellena nada.

Comment: A mí me salen rellenas las áreas positivas con este código. ¿No era eso lo que buscabas @RJSP? De hecho, he votado positivo esta respuesta